Locally compact groupoid with range map restricted to isotropy groupoid is open
Suppose the action groupoid =⋉, where  is a compact group and 
a locally compact space is such that stabilizer subgroups of H under the action of $H$  are isomorphic to each other.
Can this be an example of a groupoid such that the range map restricted to its isotropy subgroupoid is open.
What I think is  the following:
Let $G' = \cup_{x\in X}G^{x}_{x}$ be the isotropy subgroupoid of $G$.
For $x_{0}\in X$,  the isotropy subgroup $G^{x_{0}}_{x_{0}}= x_{0}\times H_{x_{0}}$, where $H_{x_{0}}$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $H$ with respect to $x_{0}$ under the action of $H$ over $X$.
Since $H_{x}$ and $H_{x_{0}}$ are isomorphic for every $x$, we can say that $\{\delta_{x}\times \phi_{x}^{*}\beta \}$ form a haar system for $G'$ where $\phi_{x}^*\beta$ is the haar measure on $H_{x}$ coming from the isomorphism with $H_{x_{0}}$ having normalised haar measure $\beta$ and $\delta_{x}$ is the point mass at $x$. Hence range map is open.

Hi and welcome to MSE! Please show us what you've tried to solve the problem; we don't generally accept questions that don't. Also, please use MathJax to format the contents of your question, see here for help.
